# How do I get nearest grid intersection?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to draw a circle at the closest line intersection on a grid relative to the mouse. I draw the grid from the center outward with varying x and y separations. I attempted to get the correct coord but its off. How do I get the correct coordinate?

Here's my code:

```
class Grid : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
public:

    Grid(unsigned int Xsep, unsigned int Ysep, unsigned int CanvasW, unsigned int CanvasH);

    virtual ~Grid() {};

    void setFillColor(const sf::Color &color);

    void setSize(unsigned int Xsep, unsigned int Ysep, unsigned int CanvasW, unsigned int CanvasH);

    unsigned int xSep = 0;
    unsigned int ySep = 0;

private:

 virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
    {
        // apply the entity's transform -- combine it with the one that was passed by the caller
        states.transform *= getTransform(); // getTransform() is defined by sf::Transformable

        // apply the texture
        states.texture = &m_texture;

        // you may also override states.shader or states.blendMode if you want
        states.blendMode = sf::BlendMode(sf::BlendMode::SrcAlpha, sf::BlendMode::OneMinusDstColor,sf::BlendMode::Add);

        // draw the vertex array
        target.draw(m_vertices, states);
    }

    sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
    sf::Texture m_texture;
};

Grid::Grid(unsigned int Xsep, unsigned int Ysep, unsigned int CanvasW, unsigned int CanvasH)
{

    xSep = Xsep;
    ySep = Ysep;

    m_vertices.setPrimitiveType(sf::Lines);
    m_vertices.clear();

    for (int i=((CanvasW/2)-Xsep); i > 0; i-=Xsep)
    {
        m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(i,0));
        m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(i,CanvasH));
        m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(CanvasW-i,0));
        m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(CanvasW-i,CanvasH));
    }

    for (int i=((CanvasH/2)-Ysep); i > 0; i-=Ysep)
    {
        m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(0,i));
        m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(CanvasW,i));
        m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(0,CanvasH-i));
        m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(CanvasW,CanvasH-i));
    }

    m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(0,CanvasH / 2));
    m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(CanvasW,CanvasH / 2));
    m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(CanvasW / 2, 0));
    m_vertices.append(sf::Vector2f(CanvasW / 2,CanvasH)); 

}

int RoundNum(int num, int difference)
{
     int rem = num % difference;
     return rem >= 5 ? (num - rem + difference) : (num - rem);
}

sf::CircleShape point(5);
point.setOrigin(point.getRadius()/2,point.getRadius()/2);
sf::Vector2f mousepos = mapPixelToCoords(sf::Mouse::getPosition(*this));
point.setPosition(RoundNum(mousepos.x,grid.xSep),RoundNum(mousepos.y,grid.ySep));
draw(point);
```

Comment: What is wrong with the coordinates you are getting? How do you know that they are "off"? ... By the way, you appear to be populating the vertices of your grid inward from the borders, not outward from the center.

Comment: Its varies by the x/y seperation how much it its off. Also the for loop starts at the canvas center ie i=CanvasW/2 therfore it should be going from center out.

Comment: Right, since you count down from width/2 the locations are all uniformly spaced from the center. And that part seems to work OK, presumably.

Comment: Still unsure what is going wrong. Can you give a specific example? Actual numbers would help, such as you click at (43,57), the nearest grid point is (45,55), but the center of the point appears to be at (48,62) (or whatever numbers actually occur when you try it).

Comment: [http://imgur.com/tqLBm6X](http://imgur.com/tqLBm6X) as you can see its way off

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two things to look into.

First, you set up the grid lines to be uniformly spaced from the center outward.
But `RoundNum(mousepos.x,grid.xSep)` snaps your position to a line of a grid that is spaced
uniformly from wherever `x` is zero. Presumably that point is not at the center of the
rectangle. Is it at a corner of the rectangle? Since the width of the rectangle
is not a multiple of `2 * grid.xSep`, the grid aligned with the corner will be offset
from a grid aligned with a corner. This is true for the y-coordinates as well.

**Edited** in response to a comment: One way to solve a problem like this is to subtract width/2 from your x-coordinate, then round it, then add width/2. Alternatively, find
`grid.xSep - ((width/2)%grid.xSep)`; add that value to your x-coordinate, round the result, then subtract that value. The second way is more complicated but avoids having to think about what happens if `x` in `x%n` is negative. Of course you would also do something similar with the y-coordinates.

Second, this works only when `difference` is 9 or 10:

```
    return rem >= 5 ? (num - rem + difference) : (num - rem);
```

It would work for even values of `difference` if you replace `5` with `difference/2`.
To make it work correctly for all values of `difference` (even or odd), replace `5`
with `(difference + 1)/2`.

It may also be worth confirming that this does what you want:

```
point.setOrigin(point.getRadius()/2,point.getRadius()/2);
```

It appears to be correct, but it's easy to check (just draw a `CircleShape` at a known grid point, such as the center) so you might as well make sure.

Comment: The first issue seems most likely but i have no idea how to get the correct coord relative to the gird :(

Comment: I see that unlike the second point, I didn't give any suggested solution for my first point. Sorry about that! I have edited the answer so it is more complete now.

Comment: [http://i.imgur.com/roTn4VS.png](http://i.imgur.com/roTn4VS.png) closer but still off. I applied fix in round func and heres draw code
[http://pastie.org/9644806](http://pastie.org/9644806)

Comment: I meant `RoundNum(mousepos.x - xoff, grid.xSep) + xoff`. And of course it is wise to check that `xoff` is the amount we want it to be (e.g. print to console or look at things in the debugger).

Comment: when grid is 64 xoff is 27. It's still off I'm not sure what correct value should be